# How to setup server for SMS communication for Teltonika FMB920

Tags: server, gps, tracking, gsm, teltonika

I am tring to create a vehicle tracking system based on GPS & GMS using Teltonika FMB920 tracking device. I am a bit confused on following things:

1. How to setup the server for communicating with the device.
2. How to save the data sent from the device on the server.
3. Can I use any cloud platform like Azure or AWS IoT features for this purpose.

Any guidance in this regard will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. How to setup the server for communicating with the device.

Teltonika fmbxxx typically send data using websockets TCP or UDP protocol. To setup the server correctly, the port that will be listening for data needs to be opened in the server and the server address and port need to be configured on the device with the [teltonika configurator tool](https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/Teltonika_Configurator_versions#For_FMB_series)

- [how to update server settings in configurator tool](https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/Template:FMB_GPRS_settings)

2. How to save the data sent from the device on the server.
   This depends on your use case but a good idea could be to use nosql database to save the data from device received by the server since its easier to scale when data size grows and easy to query and read the data
3. Can I use any cloud platform like Azure or AWS IoT features for this purpose.

AFAIK yes you can. essentially what is need is server instance with a websocket client application that can receive data from tcp/udp protocol